# Recognizing Principal Ideals

Tags: ring-theory, algebraic-number-theory, quadratic-integer-rings

In the ring $\mathbb{Z}[\sqrt{6}]$, the ideal $(2,\sqrt{6})$ simplifies to $(\sqrt{6}-2)$, while in the ring $\mathbb{Z}[\sqrt{10}]$, the ideal $(2,\sqrt{10})$ is not principal (I think). Is there some simple way to tell if a finitely generated ideal is actually principal?

Comment: In which rings? From your tags I assume in integer rings of quadratic extensions. And I would assume those which are not PIDs, or would your question contain the question for an easy criterion whether such a ring is a PID?

Comment: @TorstenSchoeneberg I am chiefly concerned with quadratic integer rings which are not principal ideal domains, but if a criterion exists which can work for the ring of integers for any primitive extension of the rationals, that'd be great.

Comment: Related question: https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1031546/help-unmasking-a-disguised-principal-ideal

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Especially with quadratic integer rings, but also for more general rings of integers, the norm is really useful. Note that if $I=(a)$, then $N(I)=|N_{K/\Bbb Q}(a)|$ where $K$ is the quotient field of your quadratic integer ring (this holds more generally in number fields.)

Thus if you can show that there exists no $a$ in your ring with $|N(a)|=N(I)$, it follows that the ideal is not principal. In the example, there exists no $a \in \Bbb Z[\sqrt{10}]$ such that $|N(a)|=2$, because the equation $x^2-10y^2=\pm 2$ has no solutions with $x,y \in \Bbb{Z}$.

Answer (score 4):

If you don't know whether the domain is a principal ideal domain or not, then I suppose there is no simple way to know whether any ideal generated by two numbers might be a "disguised" principal ideal.

You *could* try computing the GCD of the generators using the Euclidean algorithm, probably using the absolute value of the norm as the Euclidean function. In quadratic integer rings, that would be $|N(a + b \sqrt{d})| = |a^2 - db^2|$.

For example, in the case of $\langle 2, \sqrt{6} \rangle$, we see that $N(2) = 4$ and $N(\sqrt{6}) = -6$. Then we solve $\sqrt{6} = 2m + r$ such that $|N(r)| < 4$. The fundamental unit is $5 + 2 \sqrt{6}$. Since $\sqrt{6}$ ensures $db^2$ is even, $a^2$ must be odd, and so must $a$ be. But multiplying by $2$ ensures the $a$ and $b$ of $2m$ are both even, so $N(r) = \pm 1$ is impossible.

Is $N(r) = \pm 2$ possible? It is. Thus we find that $\sqrt{6} = (2 \times 1) + (2 + \sqrt{6})$. And from there it readily follows that $2 = (2 + \sqrt{6})(2 - \sqrt{6}) + 0$. Furthermore, $\langle 2 - \sqrt{6} \rangle = \langle 2 + \sqrt{6} \rangle$. And since $\langle 2 \rangle \in \langle 2 + \sqrt{6} \rangle$ and $\langle \sqrt{6} \rangle \in \langle 2 + \sqrt{6} \rangle$, we conclude $\langle 2, \sqrt{6} \rangle$ is a principal ideal, despite not having been presented as such.

Now try to do the same thing with $\langle 2, \sqrt{10} \rangle$, to solve $\sqrt{10} = 2m + r$ such that $|N(r)| < 4$. Once again we see that $r$ with unit norm is impossible. And no number in this domain has norm $\pm 2$, since no perfect square in $\mathbb{Z}$ has $2$ nor $8$ for a least significant digit. Likewise, no number in this domain has norm $\pm 3$, since no perfect square ends $3$ or $7$.

That our Euclidean algorithm fails for our chosen Euclidean function suggests $\langle 2, \sqrt{10} \rangle$ is not a principal ideal. But even if it was principal, that would mean there is some *number* in this domain with the same norm as our ideal, and we already saw there isn't. We must therefore conclude $\langle 2, \sqrt{10} \rangle$ is not a principal ideal after all.

Is this simple? No, I don't suppose that it is.